# Is there any replacement for Firebase Crashlytics?

Tags: android, ios, swift, react-native, crashlytics

I want a replacement SDK for Firebase Crashlytics that i can deploy it's server on my company's servers.In other language i want to localize this SDK just for my company and all my crash logs and information stay in my company (for security reasons).
I found sentry SDK capture exception.Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have another alternative SDK for Firebase Crashlytics.

- **Sentry**
- **Bugsnag**
- **Embrace**
- **Instabug**
- **New Relic** etc..